# Positioning the text straight in horizontal stacked bar in d3

Tags: d3.js

[Output that I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDE8i.png)   I have a problem with positioning the text in horizontal stacked bar, this is the data set  that I receive from back-end

```
data set = [
    { label: "FIFO", "Normal": 55, "Ab Normal": 40 },
    { label: "Urine MAY", "Normal": 5, "Ab Normal": 30 },
    { label: "LL", "Normal": 20, "Ab Normal": 30 },
    { label: "AC", "Normal": 10, "Ab Normal": 40 },
    { label: "Specialty", "Normal": 55, "Ab Normal": 15 },
];
```

I want the text inside the bar to be straight(-90) , but it is inverted

Comment: Try adding a `rotate(-90)` to the `transform` attribute on the text elements in question. See here for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Rotate

Comment: This is a strange problem to have since usually text is horizontal not vertical. You probably rotated your text somewhere in the code.